# Someone want to mine with my bitcoin (www.elitecoinmine.com) Promises?

Tags: mining-theory, fraud, antminer

I just signed up to ask this Question. Shoort story about me: I don't know much about crypto currency, just spend 50Eur once to buy some Dash.

Anyway, there's a guy writing me via my instagram and then via whatsapp since almost a year, he always ask me to buy Bitcoin (about 150$ at least) and he will be my manager and www.elitecoinmine.com will be using my bc to mine, and he talks about very fast profit (in about 48 hours).
So I asked one of my close friends who is more into crpyto currency and he was lauginh about it, like "How can someone mine with your bc, thats rediculious".

Now I want to ask you guys, is it even possible that someone mine with my bc?? or is this a bad joke at all, i can see that i might rent some equipment to do mining, which i would never do, but using my bc to mine??

He always talks about that they work with antminers S9 (whatever that means)

and yes it's all about www.elitecoinmine.com, if someone got some expirience please let me know, i'm very puzzled since I don't know that much about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

**This is a scam.**  Block all contact with this person and do not send any money, passwords, keys, or anything else.

Your friend is right, there is no such thing as mining "with" somebody's Bitcoin.  Mining requires specialized hardware (such as the AntMiner S9, which is a real device) but if one has that hardware, one doesn't need access to additional coins or anything else.

The scam will probably be organized in a way that it looks like you keep control of the coins throughout the process, and such that it is not obvious that your coins have been transferred to the scammer.  But in the end, when you try to get them back, you will find that you can't.